# XML string to Binary

Tags: c#, xml

I want to convert XML string to binary.

Here is my sample xml

```
 XDocument doc = new XDocument(
    new XElement("Root",
        new XElement("Child", "content")
  ));
```

Edited - Want to convert doc.OuterXml to binary.

Want to convert doc.ToString() to binary.

my xml is in UTF-16 and want to convert it into Base 64 Binary

Please suggest me how to achive this.

Comment: Convert it to binary *how*? Using ASCII encoding? Unicode? Something else?

Comment: `XDocument` doesn't have an `OuterXml` property. What do you mean by binary?  Are you writing to a file?  A stream? (hint: both of these can be done with `doc.Save`). Do you want a byte array in memory? What encoding?

Comment: I want to convert this xml to binary and pass it to request xml of service.
here is the sample binary provided to me

PD94bWwgdmVyc2lvbj0iMS4wIj8+CjxUSE1haW5XcmFwcGVyIHhtbG5zPSJodHRwOi8vZ3VpZGV3aXJlLmNvbS9w

Comment: my xml is in UTF-16 and want to convert it into Base 64 Binary